# HighCharts how to place dates in the Y-Axis (vertical axis)

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to build a highchart that looks like this:

[image: Column chart, date example]

For some reason I can't seem to find an example of how to get dates in the Y Axis, only the X Axis.

Does anyone have a JSFiddle they could share of how to do this?

Comment: By 'dates' you mean place strings there, they are not of type datetime, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you just need to set `type` of Y axis as:

```
yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
}
```

...and write other code like if X axis has type 'datetime' but keep in mind that axes were swapped. Also don't forget that you need to customize your tooltip to format the datetime value (use the property `tooltip: formatter`). Also as I see in your picture you need to customize datetime labels of your Y axis. You may use the property `labels: formatter` for X axis.

So there is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5hnBP/5/

Comment: Thanks, you got me going in the right direction without a lot of conversion date work.  ref: http://jsfiddle.net/no1uknow/5hnBP/8/